# JS: can't open links other than first

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm Looping through rows, generating links with each their identical value, in this case.

Shown here:

```
@foreach (var article in Model.Articles)
   {
      <tr class="etc">
          @if (Model.Order.Status == Model.Orders.Status.Blocked)
                        {
                            <td id="buttonDeleteOrderLine" description="@article.Description" name="@Model.Order.FullName" value="@article.LineId" ><a href="#">Delete Line</a></td>
                        }
```

**Value="*value*" is unique in this case!**

My JS:

```
    $('#buttonDeleteOrderLine').on('click', function () {
    var DOL = $(this);
    var orderDescription = DOL.attr("description");
    var customerName = DOL.attr("name");
    var lineID = DOL.attr("value");
```

I'm getting links for each row, and they're also clickable. However, only the first one actually works (shows a modal, not included in JS Code)

[image: Not nessecairy]

So I need a way, to search the class 'buttonDeleteOrderLine' (because the ID changes), and yet get the info from the clicked link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was quite simple actually,

Set

> `id="buttonDeleteOrderLine"` to  `class="buttonDeleteOrderLine"`

and I've changed:

> `$('#buttonDeleteOrderLine').on('click', function () {`

to:

> `$('.buttonDeleteOrderLine').on('click', function () {`

It now works and gets the correct information of each link, including the sub-information.

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one element per `ID`, where you can have any number of elements per `Class`.